# Findviewbyid always returns null

Tags: android, android-layout, null, android-imageview

I am Programmatically adding views to a linear layout (works fine). However when I try to get 1 specific imageview, ivBsquadBroken, that image view always returns null. All of the other viewes return correctly. I have simplified it down to just the two imageviews and nothing I have tried will return that view. The other imageview returns correctly and I can set the image, set visibility, etc.

Also, not sure why but if I declare R.layout.rowbridge_squads as the correct relative layout instead of a linear layout, it breaks.

Thanks for the help!

Code to Programmatically add the relative layout to the linear layout.

```
ArrayList<Squadron> tmpships = ((ExtendedApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getCurrentSquad();

    LinearLayout tmpLL = (LinearLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.llBSquadList);
    tmpLL.removeAllViews();

    for(int i = 0; i <= tmpships.size() - 1; i++){

        LinearLayout shiplayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rowbridge_squads, tmpLL, false);

        ImageView tmpIB = (ImageView) shiplayout.findViewById(R.id.ivBsquadicon);
        ***!! always returns null - - >*** ImageView blasted = (ImageView) shiplayout.findViewById(R.id.ivBsquadBroken);
        Squadron tmpsquad = tmpships.get(i);
```

Layout being inflated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/llBrowsquaditem"
android:background="@color/bridge_cream">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ivBsquadicon"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ivBsquadBroken"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How about not casting to both and simply using `View shiplayout = ...`

Comment: Casting to an imageview object should not break the Findviewbyid process. It doesn't in any other situation. I am not sure why this one is different

Comment: Is not it ( `LinearLayout shiplayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rowbridge_squads, tmpLL, false);` ) RelativeLayout ? I mean the layout which has been inflated is RelativeLayout. RelativeLayout can not be be cast to LinearLayout.

Comment: Correct, but if I try to cast it to relative, it breaks. Not sure how to capture what the error is

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I have multiple configuration for landscape and portrait that I hadn't updated.

User error...